# Saving complex structures to shared preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences

I need to save a complex set of `preferences`, essentially and `HashMap` containing arrays of other `hashmaps` as values for its keys.

How can I save this to `preferences`, or should I save such `preferences` in another manner? Should I create an object for preferences and serialize it to a file? If so, how can this be done please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forgotten about this, but thought I would post an answer after all this time. I generally use serialization to store such items as follows.

1. Create a LinkedHashMap or an array of LinkedHashMaps with the info you want to store.
2. Choose a name, then save it (Object being the Map or Array) to disk as follows:

```
public void serializeObject(Object object, String filename) {

        try {

            File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            oos.writeObject(object);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

3. To retrieve, proceed as follows:

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), Filename);
if (file.exists()) map = (LinkedHashMap) loadSerialisedClassFile(file);

public Object loadSerialisedClassFile(File file) {

        try {

            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            Object object = ois.readObject();
            return object;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use Paper its a fast NoSQL Databse. easy to create and store data in this. 
Here is the link.
https://github.com/pilgr/Paper

Answer (score 1):

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) only stored primative values in key/value pairs. As a result I don't think this is the best way to store a `HashMap` of `Array`s of `HashMap`s - that is unless the data can be flattened in such a way that it makes sense (if you're using a number of `HashMap`s which are really key value pairs is there no way you could store that data as regular key value pairs?).

If the data structure is really that complicated you need to look into other storage options. Depending on the length I'd probably just use a `SQLite` database. It's easy to set up, can be accessed anywhere within your app, persistant like stored preferences and fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complex data structure, and you want to store it in shared prefs, then you might consider creating a to_json() method for your object.
and then of course a from_json(String json) method.

Comment: I do not recommend this approach. Android's built-in json library breaks when serializing complex structures. The best approach is to serialize a class instance to file using the Serialization interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson library

> Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object.

By using Gson you can convert your class structure to json format then store it as string format to **shared preferences** and when you want to get that class structure back you can use again gson, gson will convert your json format to again in java object.

For more [Check Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: GSON is not only unreliable in my experience, but also but poorly structured and documented. I highly recommend that you avoid including it in any project.